# Rails ajax calling patch or put request in coffee script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am trying to make a profile page for my users and wanting to have a few check-boxes for users to instantly update profile without pressing save.

I am trying to use check-box to call coffee script and do an ajax call to update function in user controller. But it shows "PATCH localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)" in the console.

IN VIEW

```
- @sectors = ['music', 'math', 'chinese']
- @sectors.each do |sector|
  p
    = sector
  = check_box_tag sector, sector, false, class: "interest-check-box", data: { user_id: current_user.id, interest: sector }
```

IN JS.COFFEE

```
$(".interest-check-box").click ->
  console.log("Checked")
  checked = undefined
  if $(this).is(":checked")
    checked = true
  else
    checked = false
  $.ajax
    type: "PATCH"
    url: "/users/" + $(this).data('user-id')
    dataType: "json"
    data:
      _method: "PUT"
      id: $(this).data("user-id")
      checked: checked
      interest: $(this).data("interest")
  return
```

IN CONTROLLER, I would only wanting to test redirecting first, it is called but always PATCH localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @member = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.destroy
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
    end
  end

  def update
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what appends if you point your browser (or better some command line tool like `curl --request PUT ...`) on http://localhost:3000/ ?

Comment: Why do you have both `_method: "PUT"` and `type: "PATCH"`? What does `rake routes` say for `Users`? What is the path & parameters on the server console output?